# How to make the right mask?

Tags: regex, logic

I'm checking valid strings for "**Invalid format**".

The minimum length of the string is **5** characters, the maximum is **32** (`/[a-z\d_\.]{5,32}/`).

The "**Invalid format**" error occurs. It occurs if the string:

1. Starts with three or more digits (one or two digits are acceptable);
2. It starts and ends with the `_` character;
3. Contains a dot after which there are less than four characters starting with the letter.

I wrote an expression that works for the first two conditions, but I don't understand how to implement the third condition? If possible, then give an example of a separate expression, I do not understand exactly how to do it with the dot symbol.

```
^(?!(?:_|\d{3,}))[a-z\d_\.]{5,32}(?<!_)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/W9njMe/1

Thanks.

Comment: Please forgive me for my English, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Try `^(?!\d{3})(?!_.*_$)(?!.*\.[a-z].{0,2}$)[a-z\d_.]{5,32}$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9njMe/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern with an assertion, that does not match a dot after the last occurence of `[a-z]` when there are 1-4 chars left till the end of the string.

```
^(?!_|\d{3})(?!.*[a-z](?=.{1,4}$)[a-z\d_]*\.)[a-z\d_.]{5,32}$(?<!_)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!_|\d{3})` Assert not `_` or 3 digits
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is to the right is not

  - `.*[a-z]` Match the last occurrence of `[a-z]`
  - `(?=.{1,4}$)` Assert 1-4 chars till end of string
  - `[a-z\d_]*\.` Match match a `.`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[a-z\d_.]{5,32}$` Match 5-32 chars in the string
- `(?<!_)` Assert not `_` to the left

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bRa1Kd/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?!_|\d{3})(?!.*\.([^a-z]|.{4}))[a-z\d_.]{5,32}(?<!_)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W9njMe/4)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!_|\d{3})`: Fail the match if `_` is first character or if there are 3 digits at the start
- `(?!.*\.([^a-z]|.{4}))`: Fail the match if dot is not followed by a non-letter or if there are 4 characters after dot
- `[a-z\d_.]{5,32}`: Match allowed characters 5 to 32 times
- `(?<!_)`: Negative lookbehind to fail the match if `_` is last character
- `$`: End